# Error on rename for a column on a temporal table

Tags: sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I've come across an issue when renaming a column in a temporal table. I'm using entity framework to generate migrations, so most of the original SQL is generated, but that doesn't affect my issue.

To reproduce the problem first create a table (I've done a blank database, with just this table).

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable1] 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar(2000)] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then turn on system versioning

```
ALTER TABLE [TestTable1]
ADD
  SysStartTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_SysStartTestTable1 DEFAULT DATEADD(d, -1, SYSUTCDATETIME()),
  SysEndTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_SysEndTestTable1 DEFAULT CONVERT(datetime2(0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
ALTER TABLE [TestTable1] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TestTable1History))
```

Now rename the column (no issues with this one, it doesn't matter if you enter data in the table or not)

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.TestTable1.UserId', @newname = N'OldUserId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
```

Next I needed to add a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1] ADD [UserId] [int]
```

No problems so far, next I update the data using the old user to populate the new user.

Now I make my new column not nullable and I add an index on my new column (these might not be necessary to create the issue) .

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1] ALTER COLUMN [UserId] [int] NOT NULL
CREATE INDEX [IX_UserId] ON [dbo].[TestTable1]([UserId])
```

Now I get rid of my original column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1] DROP COLUMN [OldUserId]
```

Because I'm using EF migrations, I need to have a reverse script to roll the database back to the earlier version.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1] ADD [OldUserId] [uniqueidentifier]
DROP INDEX [IX_UserId] ON [dbo].[TestTable1]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1] DROP COLUMN [UserId]
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.TestTable1.OldUserId', @newname = N'UserId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
```

The rename fails with the error `Invalid object name ' '.`

If I don't drop the column then I can rename it back, so it must be something to do with dropping the column. If temporal tables are not enabled then this also works just fine.

Comment: I ran your scripts as provided and did not encounter any error on 2016.

Comment: and so have I and apart of this line `[Description] nvarchar(2000) NULL,` all was good